# how to not select uitextfield that is in uitableviewcell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uitextfield

I am trying to load a new view from a tableview:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method that happens when the uitableviewcell is selected, but because I have a custom uitextfield on that uitableviewcell it selects that text field instead of selecting the uitableviewcell.. how do I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know what your goal is... But
you can solve your problem by using *CGRectMake(110, 10, 185, 30)]*

```
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.selectionStyle= UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 10, 185, 30)];
    textField.clearsOnBeginEditing = NO;
    textField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
    textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    textField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    textField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
    textField.delegate = self;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:textField];
```

This way, the UItextField will be on the right half of the tableView and you can touch the left half of the tableView to select a row.

Comment: okay cool, yea I think thats the best solution at the end of the day.. It seems alot of the crap I am trying to do just is not feesable :( thanks for the response.